# Filter Pandas by a Column with List Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a pandas `DataFrame` that contains a column with list values

```
> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
      {'name' : {0 : 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'baz', 3: 'foz'}, 
       'Attributes': {0: ['x', 'y'], 1: ['y', 'z'], 2: ['x', 'z'], 3: []}
      })

   name    Attributes
0  foo     ['x', 'y']
1  bar     ['y', 'z']
2  baz     ['x', 'z']
3  foz     []
```

How can the DataFrame be filtered for only those rows don't contain a certain value, e.g. `'y'`, in the lists:

```
2  baz     ['x', 'z']
3  foz     []
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can convert the series of list to a dataframe and compare if all the columns are not equal to `y`:

```
# is they aren't actual list : df['Attributes'] = df['Attributes'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df[pd.DataFrame(df['Attributes'].tolist()).ne('y').all(1)]
```

---

```
  Name Attributes
2  baz     [x, z]
```

If they are not actual lists:

```
df[df['Attributes'].str.count('y').eq(0)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response!  I believe I am running into an error with your solution because some of my rows have empty lists.  I am updating my question accordingly.

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil empty lists are hard to copy and replicate, can you try `df[df['Attributes'].str.join('|').str.count('y').eq(0)]` , else please post a `df.to_dict()1 for the sample in the question

Comment: Added the pandas declaration from a dict

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil i get the expected outpt using `df[pd.DataFrame(df['Attributes'].tolist()).ne('y').all(1)]` which is the first solution in my answer, can you try once

Comment: Ah, the problem was that I my original index was not perfectly `0...3`.  Your solution works with `...all(1).to_list()]`

Answer (score 1):

This should work (although it's not very elegant)

```
def filter_data_frame(df):
    good_index = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if "y" not in df.iloc[i,1]:
            good_index.append(i)

return df.iloc[good_index, :]
```